# Spatie Roles and Permissions with Laravel Sanctum Authentication for API

Tags: permissions, laravel-sanctum

I have built an API in Laravel using Sanctum for authentication. This is working great. I am now able to login in Postman to retrieve my token, then use that token to authenticate further requests.

I have also implemented Spatie Roles and Permissions for granular user permissions.  Again, this is working fine. In my unit tests I create a new factory user, assign it the permissions I am testing and verify features are either authorised or unauthorised.

My problem is combining the two.  How can I use Postman to login using Sanctum whilst honouring the Spatie permissions assigned to my logged in user? Every attempt I make authenticates me fine, but does not authorise me for anything.

Comment: Is anyone able to help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Were you able to get this sorted? I can't seem to figure out how to get it to use Spatie's roles over Sanctum's abilities.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function authenticate(AuthRequest $request){

    $credentials = [
      'username' => $request->username,
      'password' => $request->password
    ];

    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
      return response()->json(['error' => 'The provided credentials are incorrect.',], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    $user = Auth::user();
   
    # get permissions from spartie #
    $abilities = $user->getAllPermissions()->pluck('name')->toArray();

    $token = $user->createToken('', $abilities)->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer',
      'access_token' => $token,
      'abilities' => $abilities
    ]);
 }
```

In Route api.php

```
Route::get('/URL'[CONTROLLER::class,'METHOD'])->middleware('permission:PERMISSION');
```